# Is Method variable in a singleton class is thread safe in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have singleton class named **TransactionCreateTemplate** and this class has a instance method with one parameter **def mail_payload(json_params)** my question is, if we create local variable inside the **mail_payload** method whether that local variable is thread safe?

```
class TransactionCreateTemplate
  include Singleton
  def mail_payload(json_params)
    transaction = Transaction.new(params[:name])
  end
end
class Transaction
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

In the above one, whether **transaction**  local variable inside the **mail_payload** method is thread safe?, since it is singleton class, only one object is created and that same object is used by different threads, i am confused.

Comment: `transaction` is local to `mail_payload`.

Comment: ... Every call to `mail_payload` creates a new local `transaction` reference. That's what local variables are, as opposed to *instance* variables.

Comment: If you're asking if the `transaction` reference is thread-safe, e.g., you're spinning up threads that operate on `transaction`, that depends on what `Transaction` is.

Comment: @DaveNewton **transaction** is a simple class, i didn't asked about the **transaction** reference. also added the sample **transaction** class

Comment: You are *explicitly* asking about the `transaction` reference. Only one `TransactionCreateTemplate` instance is created. `transaction` is a *local variable*, *not an instance variable*, so there's no shared state. If *other* threads access `transaction` its thread safety depends on the `Transaction` implementation--as is it is *not* thread safe, but that's only relevant if other threads access the `transaction` reference created in `mail_payload`.

Comment: @DaveNewton is it mean for every call(even with same object instance) to **mail_payload** method creates new **method_call stack** and local variables created, are stored in the respective stack created. am I right?

Comment: ... Yes, that's what local variables are, as opposed to *instance* variables.

Comment: The `transaction =` assignment is superfluous, it doesn’t do anything because the local variable is never used afterwards.